# how to find the only object property with a value

Tags: jquery, object

When a jQuery ajax call is made, the resulting jqXHR variable `data` is passed to a render function `renderData`, below. The function determines where the data has come from by populating just one of the `$type` object's properties.

What's a neat way to get find out which property got populated, and in turn where the data came from?

```
function renderData(data){
    var $type = {
        contact : $(data).filter('#contact'),
        details : $(data).find('#details'),
        other   : $(data).find('#other')
    };
    // Get the populated property and store its value in "endResult"
    endResult.appendTo('#wrapper').hide().fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Corrected, seems like an OK question.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to find the property and encapsulate it in a function.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/E9J4y/)**

```
var type1 = {
    contact : 'a',
    details : undefined,
    other   : undefined
};

var type2 = {
    contact : undefined,
    details : undefined,
    other   : 'b'
};

var type1Prop = getPopulatedProperty(type1);
alert(type1Prop + ' = ' + type1[type1Prop]);
var type2Prop = getPopulatedProperty(type2);
alert(type2Prop + ' = ' + type2[type2Prop]);

function getPopulatedProperty(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop] !== undefined && obj[prop] !== null && obj[prop] !== '') {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was having difficulty with the condition, but this is exactly what I was after.

Comment: Correction - I thought this was the correct answer, but for some reason, the first property is always returned by `getPopulatedProperty()`. The console tells me it has the value [object Object]

Comment: You need to change your condition in the function then as even if they're empty they're still objects. The function assumes that to be empty the property needs to be undefined, null or the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are the one creating the object as well, right? Why not simply add a property to the object that tells you what it is for?

For instance, if you create the object by echoing JSON from PHP, you can add a "type" property:

```
echo('{"type": "contactForm", ...your data goes here}');
```

That way, your render function becomes:

```
function renderData(data){
    var $type = data.type;
    ...
};
```

Saves you from having to loop through the properties to find out something you should already know if you are the author of the object. If you are using an object on which you have no control, Daniel's solution should do it.